# Is it possible to force explicit implementation of an interface (or parts of it)?

Tags: c#, .net

Lets say I have an interface like this:

```
public interface MyInterface
{
    int Property1
    {
        get;
    }

    void Method1();
    void Method2();
}
```

Is there any way to force the implementer of the interface to implement parts of it explicitly? Something like:

```
public interface MyInterface
{
    int Property1
    {
        get;
    }

    explicit void Method1();
    explicit void Method2();
}
```

Edit: As to why I care about whether the interface is implemented explicitly or not; it's not like it matters as far as functionality goes, but it could be helpful to hide some unnecessary details from people using the code.

I'm trying to mimic multiple inheritance in my system, using this pattern:

```
public interface IMovable
{
    MovableComponent MovableComponent
    {
         get;
    }
}

public struct MovableComponent
{
    private Vector2 position;
    private Vector2 velocity;
    private Vector2 acceleration;

    public int Method1() 
    {
        // Implementation
    }

    public int Method2() 
    {
        // Implementation
    }

}

public static IMovableExtensions
{
    public static void Method1(this IMovable movableObject) 
    {
        movableObject.MovableComponent.Method1();
    }

    public static void Method2(this IMovable movableObject) 
    {
        movableObject.MovableComponent.Method2();
    }
}

public class MovableObject : IMovable
{
    private readonly MovableComponent movableComponent = new MovableComponent();

    public MovableComponent MovableComponent 
    {
        get { return movableComponent; }  // Preferably hiddem, all it's methods are available through extension methods.
    } 
}

class Program
{
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
          MovableObject movableObject = new MovableObject();
          movableObject.Method1();   // Extension method
          movableObject.Method2();   // Extension method
          movableObject.MovableComponent    // Should preferably be hidden.

     }
}
```

If the MovableComponent property was implemented explicitly, it would, in most cases, be hidden from whoever was using the class. Hope that explanation wasn't too horrible.

Comment: Are you looking for [virtual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645767(v=vs.71).aspx)?  That should allow you to declare an explicit method in this.

Comment: You cannot implement parts of an Interface. It's all or nothing.

Comment: Why do you care if it's implemented explicitly or implicitly?

Comment: Don't mimic multiple inheritance. It's not part of the C# language. Get over that and implement things the C# way.

Comment: Doing it the "C# way" would force me to implement the same interfaces in hundreds of different classes. Also, as far as I know, composition isn't an anti-pattern, so I don't see the problem.

Comment: forcing explicit interfaces is what all we are looking for replacing "friend" keyword from c++!!! Great!!! We need it!

Comment: Yes, that's right. But goal of hiding is also meaningful when you are implementing parent-child classes where parent should know its children, and vice versa. Without hiding one of the fields you can't build up solid architecture.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it is not possible to force implementers to pick explicit or implicit implementation of an interface.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called an abstract class

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: No. it's not what he is looking for. There is a reason why you want to use interfaces to encapsulate functionality rather than restricting functionality insurance to a baseclass derivation.

Comment: Abstract classes do not meet every use case, for instance I had an interface to identify the primary key of an entity class for a generic engine, however company practice was to use table name + id for that property. The interface was to be applied explicitly because was mainly an alias.

Answer (score -1):

> If the MovableComponent property was implemented explicitly, it would, in most cases, be hidden from whoever was using the class.

The goal of explicit interface implementation is not to *hide* the implementation, it's to allow for collisions between interfaces which define the same constraint but cannot abide by the same implementation.
Due to this, it becomes inevitable necessary to hide all but one of the colliding implementations when using the real type, instead only "revealing" it when the specific interface type is being used. But that is not the primary purpose, it is just a logical consequence from having to resolve the ambiguity in some way that the developer can actively choose the right implementation at the right time.

Secondly, as the interface designer, you should worry yourself about specific implementation nor how the implementing class gets handled by a third party. You're crossing a few boundaries here and trying to effect change from the wrong origin point.